# Why doesn't the instantiated controller show my message?

Tags: angularjs

In my angular HotorNot games/show.haml code this doesn't work:

```
.game{'ng-controller' => 'GamesCtrl as game'}
  %h1 Hi {{game.player}}, Is this person Hot or Not?
```

while this does:

```
.game{'ng-controller' => 'GamesCtrl as game'}
  %h1 Hi {{player}}, Is this person Hot or Not?
```

Here is my angular app and controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('HotorNot', ['ngResource']);

myApp.controller('GamesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.player = 'Stephanie';
}]);
```

Why doesn't the variable "game" work here?  I was trying to follow the advice I've heard to always use a .

Update on request, generated html:

```
<html ng-app="HotorNot" class="ng-scope"><head><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide{display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}</style>
    <title>AngularFun</title>
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param">
    <meta content="NAKzONXDIcfeoGZxqhSn8mqFvceAQBxIxvf+lso2Ibo=" name="csrf-token">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="game ng-scope" ng-controller="GamesCtrl as game">
      <h1 class="ng-binding">Hi Stephanie, Is this person Hot or Not?</h1>
      <div class="voting_image">
        <img alt="Stock footage pretty girl is listen to the music in headphones" src="http://ak1.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1321426/preview/stock-footage-pretty-girl-is-listen-to-the-music-in-headphones.jpg">
      </div>
      <button>Hot</button>
      <button>Not</button>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/app.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/angular/controllers/games_ctrl.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: can you post the generated html rather than haml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the "controller as" syntax, than your variables need to be declared on `this`, inside the controller.

This is because `GamesCtrl as game` construct tells angular that you would like the `game` to be a reference to the instance of controller constructor function.

So, if you want to use `GamesCtrl as game` than your controller needs to look like:

```
myApp.controller('GamesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  this.player = 'Stephanie';
}]);
```

Otherwise, if `player` is defined on `$scope` than it will be accessible from your view only by direct reference (`Hi {{player}} ...`), and that's because all view expressions are evaluated against current `$scope`.